# Purging details from question edit history

Tags: discussion, support

In [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/150276/6188) question the OP uploaded an image chock full of personal information.  User outflak edited the question to remove that information, but of course the original information is still visible in the edit history.

Is there anyway to purge this information?  And I can't be the first to ask this question can i?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had seen the flag requesting the redact, but at the time I could not do it, (no time and only the phone which is fiddly to do it.)

Flagging for moderator attention is the best way to ask for this kind of action.

I will now take care of it (but it needs two moderators to complete the job, so not sure how fast it will be completed.)

Thanks for bringing it to our attention again.